# Photoshop - Extracting a transparent shadow from an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency, mask

I have a layer that contains a brushed metal texture. The layer has an inner shadow effect.

[image]

I'd like to extract just that shadow with transparency, so I can later superpose the pure background and that shadow to insert some elements between them into a software.

I tried that method : [How to create alpha mask from an image in Photoshop CS/8](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-to-create-alpha-mask-from-an-image-in-photoshop-cs-8)
without success, I still have a phantom visual of the texture.

Comment: This might be easier to address with an example image.

Comment: @Sean : I have inserted the image in my question. You cna see my EDIT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only the effects applied to the layer and want the layer to be transparent, you can turn the "Fill" of the layer to 0% (not the opacity). This way all your blending options stay, but the layer is transparent

Comment: wow, that works wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you have an actual inner shadow *effect* applied to the layer.

Right-click on the Inner Shadow line in the Layers Panel and choose "Create Layer" from the context menu. That will separate the drop shadow into its own layer with the appropriate transparency/blend settings.

Comment: Alan Gilbertson is right here, in addition: if you want only the effects aplied to the layer and want the layer to be transparent, you can turn the "Fill" of the layer to 0% (not the opacity). This way all your blending options stay, but the layer is transparent

Comment: @Luuk Should be a separate A as it's a separate route too take.

Comment: @Alan Gilbertson : That was a great idea, I even didn't knwo that was possible, but that does not work for that effect.

Comment: @Luuk : Great, that works perfectly, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Will do... i mean done.

Comment: "Create Layer." I had no idea that was there. I love the stuff I learn here. :) (and most of it from Alan.)

Comment: <blush> You're way too kind. I suggested this method because it wasn't clear that he wanted to use the drop shadow in the same image. Otherwise I'd have dropped out the fill, as Luuk said, since it's the fast-and-easy way to get there. Fill-to-zero is the common way to drop effects onto a layer beneath. I do it most often with text (think "chiseled text" on a marble slab, for example -- Bevel and Emboss with Fill @ 0%).